# C# The network path was not found (Login)

Tags: c#, authentication, webforms

So after switching to a different PC using sourcetree and github, one of the 2 login functions stopped working. When I'm logging in as a customer it works fine, but when I try to login as a employee it doesn't load and gives me the error "The network patch was not found"

At the desktop pc it worked fine, now I switched to my laptop and it stopped working all of a sudden. But the strange part is that one of the 2 logins still works.

````
        {
            string databasestring = "Data Source=DESKTOP-LCG9HIA;Initial Catalog=Klantenportaal;Integrated Security=True";
            //string databasestring = "Data Source=DESKTOP-UPPSPIA;Initial Catalog=Klantenportaal;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            try
            {
                if (rbKlant.Checked == true)
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = databasestring;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT klant_id, username, wachtwoord, rol FROM Klant WHERE username = @username and wachtwoord = @wachtwoord", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", tbUsername.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@wachtwoord", tbPassword.Text));
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Session["Username"] = tbUsername.Text;
                        Session["UserID"] = dr[0].ToString();
                        con.Close();
                        dr.Close();
                        Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblError.Text = "Gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord niet correct ingevoerd, probeer opnieuw";
                        dr.Close();
                    }
                }

                else if (rbMedewerker.Checked == true)
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = databasestring;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT medewerker_id, username, wachtwoord, rol FROM Medewerker WHERE username = @username and wachtwoord = @wachtwoord", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", tbUsername.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@wachtwoord", tbPassword.Text));
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Session["Username"] = tbUsername.Text;
                        Session["MedewerkerID"] = dr[0].ToString();
                        con.Close();
                        dr.Close();
                        Response.Redirect("MedDashboard.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblError.Text = "Gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord niet correct ingevoerd, probeer opnieuw";
                        dr.Close();
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Geen keuze gemaakt tussen klant of medewerker";
                }

            }
            catch 
            {
                lblError.Text = "Onbekende fout, probeer het later nog eens";
            }

            finally
            {
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
            }```

So the login customer ("klant") actually redirects me correct, while the login for employee("medewerker") isn't fucntioning anymore.
````

Comment: You are using "Integrated Security=True" which means you are using a windows credential for the database.  SQL Server uses the user login for the credentials (not username and password).  So first the Local PC and Remote PC has to be in the same Group (or using Group Policy).  Then the user have account on Local and Remote PC.  Normally you would have SQL Server use a Window Group Account for credentials.  Then make sure the user(s) are put into the window group.  So you have to check first what window account the database is using.

Comment: `But the strange part is that one of the 2 logins still works.` Which of the two works? Which doesn't?